# Prove derivative of order $n$ at neighbourhood $x_0$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

> If 
>   $$f(x)-f(x_0)=g(x)(x-x_0)$$
>   and $g \in C^{(n-1)}(U(x_0))$, where $U(x_0)$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$, then show that $f(x)$ has a derivative $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ of order $n$ at $x_0$.

I think since $f(x)$ is continuous on its derivative of order $n-1$, I think I just need to verify that $f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)=g^{(n-1)}(x)(x-x_0)$ works and completes the proof. How do I continue it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did induction failed?

Comment: I didn't try induction and I think there are some ways can prove it directly.

Comment: Sure, you can find $n$th the derivative of a product... by induction.

Comment: By the way, $f^{(n-1)}(x) - f^{(n-1)}(x_0) = g^{(n-1)}(x)(x - x_0)$ is not true in general. I suspect virtually any pair of functions will NOT satisfy that equality given the original equation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that
\begin{align}
f(x) = f(x_0)+g(x)(x-x_0) \ \ \implies \ \ f^{(n-1)}(x) = g^{(n-1)}(x)(x-x_0)+(n-1)g^{(n-2)}(x)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)}{x-x_0} = g^{(n-1)}(x)+(n-1)\frac{g^{(n-2)}(x)-g^{(n-2)}(x_0)}{x-x_0}.
\end{align}